# Play external-display audio content on external-display's speakers and vice versa

Tags: windows-10, laptop, external-display, speakers, extended-desktop

On Windows 10, how can I play sound from windows on an external display on that displays speakers, and have windows on the internal display play sounds through the laptop speakers?

My case is a Motile M142 laptop connected to a TV over HDMI, I want content displayed on the TV to play sounds from the TV speakers, and content on the laptop display to play through the laptop speakers. I don't like having the sound of say, a game, to be coming from the TV if it's displayed on the internal screen, and vice versa.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your hardware setup? It sounds like your running a laptop with an external display, but the question is very confusing.

Comment: If you are using a separate speaker connection, likely you cannot: some speaker jacks have a swtich hard-wired to disconnect internal speaker when anything is plugged into the jack.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid  edit done, yes, it was laptop + external display

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am not using the headset jack for my setup, external audio is via HDMI

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of your sound dialog box accessed from the Control Panel in your question? If you have more than one sound device this all may be possible, it not, you might be out of luck.